# Boolean operator OR on rows of matrices

Tags: r

I would like to use the Boolean R operator OR on rows of matrices. Below you find my solution to a simple toy example using the apply function. What is the easiest/fastest way of doing this? How does this generalize to other Boolean operations?

```
b <- matrix(c(T,T,F,T,F,F),3)

apply(b,1, function(x) T %in% x)
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you are trying to do? Why aren't you using dataframes and the usual subsetting workflows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the functions [`any`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/any.html) (logical “or”) and [`all`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.html) (logical “and”) for this. In your case:

```
apply(b, 1, any)
```

As an aside, I’d avoid using `T` and `F` in code: they are normal identifiers that can be redefined elsewhere in code. `TRUE` and `FALSE` on the other hand are not constants.

Comment: I believe `rowSums` is also quite often used in this context.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the vectorized `rowSums` for this

```
rowSums(b)!=0
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or if there are only two columns, the `|` operator can also be used

```
b[,1]|b[,2]
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```